# Postgres doesn't search case-insensitive unicode regex

Tags: python, django, postgresql, unicode

I have absolutely two same databases on localhost and webfaction (I'm usin Django).
The problem with server database is that it doesn't search case insensitive unicode strings.

I have row
`name Яблоко`

I write `Word.objects.filter(name__iregex=r'(яблоко)')`
and it gives me 0 rows.

On localhost above query works.

I tried to create database with utf8 encoding, but it didn't help.
ASCII symbols work well, though.

Also, if row in database is lower-cased, then it works.
For example `name груша` will be returned (on both machines) for `Word.objects.filter(name__iregex=r'(груша)')`

Any ideas?

Comment: Enter `locale` at your local machine and on the server; what is the value of `LC_CTYPE` at your local machine and on the server?

Comment: How do I do that? I'm new to postgres.

Comment: `locale` is not a PostgreSQL command, it's a GNU/Linux command. What is the operating system in your local machine and the server? If it's Debian or Ubuntu, you can just type `locale` at the prompt.

Comment: Locale on remote machine is LANG=en_US.UTF-8 Same on local.

Comment: Please show the contents of the server's `/etc/default/locale` file.

Comment: LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="uk_UA.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="uk_UA.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="uk_UA.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="uk_UA.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="uk_UA.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="uk_UA.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="uk_UA.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="uk_UA.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="uk_UA.UTF-8"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129813/discussion-between-antonis-christofides-and-andrew-fount).