# Postgres function upper doesn't work for cyrillic (version 9.4)

Tags: sql, postgresql, unicode, webfaction

This question is similar to [Postgres doesn't search case-insensitive unicode regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40976808/postgres-doesnt-search-case-insensitive-unicode-regex)

But it appears that `upper` function doesn't work as well?
Also, it seems that encoding on server utf8

I use webfaction private postgres instance on CentOS 6 and don't know how to set locale on cluster creation.

Please, help, how to fix it.

Comment: something you don't tell: `a=# select upper('утф');
 upper
-------
 УТФ
(1 row)`

Comment: postgres=# select version();
 PostgreSQL 9.4.10 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (
Red Hat 4.8.5-4), 64-bit
(1 row)

postgres=# select upper('утф');
 upper 
-------
 утф
(1 row)

Comment: hm :/ `show server_encoding ;`?.. and `show lc_collate;`?..

Comment: show command is not found.

Comment: Output of locale command is
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=uk_UA.UTF-8
LC_TIME=uk_UA.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=uk_UA.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=uk_UA.UTF-8
LC_NAME=uk_UA.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=uk_UA.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=uk_UA.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=uk_UA.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=uk_UA.UTF-8
LC_ALL=

Comment: os env would not help here - you can create db in different locale. Though I doubt now it is locale. anyway what this shows? `select setting from pg_settings where name in ('server_encoding','lc_collate');
`?..

Comment: setting 
---------
 C
 UTF8
(2 rows)

Comment: that's the problem! `C`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change collation, like:

```
b=#  select upper('утф'  COLLATE "C"), upper('утф'  COLLATE "en_US");
 upper | upper
-------+-------
 утф   | УТФ
(1 row)
```

Changing default like:

```
b=# create table clt (a text COLLATE "C");
CREATE TABLE
b=# insert into clt select 'утф';
INSERT 0 1
b=# select upper(a) from clt;
 upper
-------
 утф
(1 row)

b=# alter table clt alter column a set data type text COLLATE "en_US";
ALTER TABLE
b=# select upper(a) from clt;
 upper
-------
 УТФ
(1 row)
```

Alternatively you can dump your data and restore it to db with right locale. On restore tables will be built with right collation:

```
b=# CREATE DATABASE not_c ENCODING 'UTF8'
   lc_ctype='en_US.utf-8'
   lc_collate='en_US.UTF-8' TEMPLATE=template0;
CREATE DATABASE
b=# \c not_c
You are now connected to database "not_c" as user "postgres".
not_c=# create table clt (a text);
CREATE TABLE
not_c=# insert into clt select 'утф';
INSERT 0 1
not_c=# select upper(a) from clt;
 upper
-------
 УТФ
(1 row)
```

Comment: How do I do it for all tables with one statement?